# Extracting numbers using regex in dataframe for heights (ft,in)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

I am trying to extract the numbers from a column in my Pandas data frame `[height]` using regular expressions. The data in the column is listed as a string using ft and in: e.g."`5ft 6in`". In order to visualize this data for future analysis I need to convert this format to be entirely in inches and as an integer. So far, I have successfully created a column `height_feet` using the first line of code below. However, I am having trouble extracting the inches `height_in`.

```
 modcloth_df = modcloth_df.assign(height_feet = modcloth_df['height'].str.extract('(\d+)'))
 modcloth_df = modcloth_df.assign(height_in = modcloth_df['height'].str.extract('((\d+)in)'))
 modcloth_df.head()
```

This results in a traceback:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

This traces back to the second line for extracting inches. I want to then assign a column as the total_height using the two integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to extract the digits from your given format
- Convert the values to `int`, calculate the value in inches and return it

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'height': ['5ft 6in', '6ft 0in']})

# function to extract numbers, convert and return inches
def convert_to_inches(x):
    values = re.findall(r'\d+', x)
    return int(values[0]) * 12 + int(values[1])


# apply the function
df['height_in'] = df.height.apply(convert_to_inches)

# output
    height  height_in
0  5ft 6in         66
1  6ft 0in         72
```

- If there are cases where the `height` column does not include `in`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'height': ['5ft 6in', '6ft 0in', '6ft']})

def convert_to_inches(x):
    values = re.findall(r'\d+', x)
    ft = int(values[0])
    try:
        inches = int(values[1])
    except IndexError:
        inches = 0
    return ft * 12 + inches


df['height_in'] = df.height.apply(convert_to_inches)


# output
    height  height_in
0  5ft 6in         66
1  6ft 0in         72
2      6ft         72
```

Comment: Thank you! at first this caused an error due to the quality of some of the data. A `try` `except` within the function ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt, without importing `re` module ([explanation of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/fXXBJc/1)):

```
import pandas as pd

modcloth_df = pd.DataFrame({'height':
                            ['5ft 6in',
                             '4ft 1in',
                             '    6in',
                             '3ft']})


modcloth_df[ ['height_feet', 'height_in'] ] = modcloth_df['height'].str.extract(r'(?:(\d+)ft)?\s*(?:(\d+)in)?').fillna(0).astype(int)
modcloth_df[ 'total_height' ] = modcloth_df[ 'height_feet' ] * 12 + modcloth_df['height_in']
print(modcloth_df)
```

Prints:

```
    height  height_feet  height_in  total_height
0  5ft 6in            5          6            66
1  4ft 1in            4          1            49
2      6in            0          6             6
3      3ft            3          0            36
```